# Filling data in grid view using textbox on button click -it show an a error inder out of bound

Tags: asp.net

when i used a textbox to insert data it show index out of bound error

```
Button_Click()

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;
    dt.Columns.Add("Name"); ///enter code here
    dt.Columns.Add("Address");
    dt.Columns.Add("Number");
    //First fill all the date present in the grid
    for (int intCnt = 0; intCnt < grd.Rows.Count; intCnt ++)
    {
    if (grd.Rows[intCnt].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = grd.Rows[intCnt].Cells[0].Value;/// at this point
    dr["Address"] = grd.Rows[intCnt].Cells[1].Value;
    dr["Number"] = grd.Rows[intCnt].Cells[2].Value;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    }
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = txt1.Text;
    dr["Address"] = txt2.Text;
    dr["Number"] = txt3.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    grd.DataSource = dt;
    grd.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

You have to use `grd.Rows.Count-1` in for loop

Button_Click()

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr;
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Address");
dt.Columns.Add("Number");

for (int intCnt = 0; intCnt < grd.Rows.Count-1; intCnt ++)
{
if (grd.Rows[intCnt].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Name"] = grd.Rows[intCnt].Cells[0].Value;/// at this point
dr["Address"] = grd.Rows[intCnt].Cells[1].Value;
dr["Number"] = grd.Rows[intCnt].Cells[2].Value;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
}
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Name"] = txt1.Text;
dr["Address"] = txt2.Text;
dr["Number"] = txt3.Text;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
grd.DataSource = dt;
grd.DataBind();
}
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

change the condition of your for loop to be `for (int intCnt = 0; intCnt < grd.Rows.Count-1; intCnt ++)
    {...}`

instead of `for (int intCnt = 0; intCnt < grd.Rows.Count; intCnt ++)
    {...}`